# Read It Later backup

Tags: links, bookmarks, pocket

I have a Read It Later account which has around 180-200 links. I want to take a backup of those links.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now you can do this [using JSON/XML](http://readitlaterlist.com/api/docs/#get)

Comment: hey thanks buddy that meant a lot !! 
I've been searching around in the Net from Morning !!

Thanks